# clearing text in a WYSIWYG text editor

Tags: jquery

I am using a HTML WYSIWYG editor Redactor

```
http://imperavi.com/redactor/examples/toolbar-external/
```

I am trying to clear the text area after an on:click event.

however because it uses div wrappers for the text editor i can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: can you show us a jsfiddle? From my experience once the wysiwyg initialize it's no more just a textarea but become an iframe. So in order to remove the content from it you need to clear the right element. The right element can be found if you inspect element like in Google Chrome.

Comment: see here http://joonhachu.blogspot.in/2013/04/how-to-clear-input-or-html-or-text-on.html it might helpful to you

Comment: The actual way to do this is `$("#selectorID").redactor('set', '');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
$('.redactor_editor').html('');
```

You simply need to bind this to an onclick event, for example:

```
$('.clear_editor').click(function () {
    $('.redactor_editor').html('');
});
```

The above will clear your Redactor text area when you click on an element with class `.clear_editor`

In case you're using Angular and [(froalaModel)], you need to set the string passed in froalaModel as undefined instead of `''`